# Git merge conflict resolution shows staged changes which I didn't do

Tags: git

Suppose following scenario.

1. I clone a central git repo and checkout master branch.
2. I do some changes in master branch in my local repo and commit.
3. Other people do changes in master branch, commit and push to the central repo
4. I try to pull master branch of central repo to mine.
5. Merge conflict occurs.

Then, if I issue `git status` command, I see that a lot of changes (which I think were done by other people in step 3) which I didn't do are automatically staged for next merge commit which I am going to do after I resolve conflicts.

My question is, after conflict resolving and committing, does above mentioned changes which were staged but not done by me go to the repo as if they were done by me?

Comment: This is why it's highly advisable for people in a multiple-developer situation to almost always use separate branches, and only do merges onto `master`...

Answer (score 6):

Every time you do a merge, a commit is created . Doing pull is effectively fetch and merge operation *(unless you are fast forwarding)*.

When a merge is successful without any conflicts, you see a direct commit *(given you are not fast forwarding)*. But when a coflict occurs, git leaves the files in coflict in a conflicted state. All other files which are merged succcessfully are placed in staged area. So when you finish your conflict, you can commit all the files together.

This commit is marked as a merge commit and other person reading the history in future should make out that this commit was caused by the merge and not for changes made by you.

Comment: I actually did the merge commit after conflict resolving and then checked git blame of those files I saw which have been staged. git blame shows that those auto staged changes were not done by me!

Comment: So, does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes. But still somewhat confused why that happens that way

Comment: Since u haven't done those changes, it's correct to say that they are not ur changes as said by git blame . And git allows us to track the timeline in the way events have occurred. The merge commit is only for depicting that the two branches got merged in this commit. Here local and remote brach.

Answer (score 1):

This normally happens if you haven't disabled some settings in your git config

The **autocrlf** option when this option is enabled and you pull something your line endings will be changed (if they are different) and your files are modified.

```
autocrlf = false
# or with this
git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

The next one is the filemode here its the same

```
filemode = false
```

Normally that are the problems. You can set these options in your git config file

```
.git/config
```

Comment: But the changes I see which have been staged does not look like line ending changes. If they were line ending changes, I would see two similar lines, one with - mark and one with + mark (signifying removal of a line with particular line ending and addition of the same line with a different line ending). Most of the changes I see are insertions.

Comment: Then your filemode changed? Can you post your config settings? But without your repos :D

Comment: I have `false` for `filemode`. Here is the local repository config.  [core]
 repositoryformatversion = 0
 filemode = false
 bare = false
 logallrefupdates = true
 symlinks = false
 ignorecase = true
 hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[remote "origin"]
 url = xxxxxxx
 fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
 remote = origin
 merge = refs/heads/master
[gui]
 wmstate = zoomed
 geometry = 887x427+2197+-11 799 192